# How to fix : Navigation bar icons still showing, when pop-up menu is opened (Full screen - Immersive sticky)

Tags: android, android-fullscreen, android-immersive, android-navigation-bar

I'm trying to achieve a full-screen application, where the user doesn't have any access to the **status- & navigation-bar**.

Preferably I would want them to be **removed completely**, but from what I've read this is not possible unless you root the device

So my question basically is: **How do I hide the navigation-bar icons, when I show the pop-up menu**?

#### BEFORE

[image: BEFORE]

#### AFTER

[image: AFTER]

So far, I have tried:

- Calling `hideNavigation()` before & after the pop-up menu is shown
- Calling `hideNavigation()` in `onCreate(), onResume() & onWindowFocusChanged()`
- Requesting focus to another view
- Trying to clear the focus from the drop-down (Failed attempt, didn't really find a way to do this)
- Changing the icon colors, "faking" it would be hidden (Failed attempt, didn't really find a way to do this)
- Using `hideNavigation()` in combination with `Handler` (Failed attempt, maybe I didn't do it correctly)
- Trying to configure some COSU/KIOSK-mode options (Perhaps there is some way to complete disable the whole navigation-bar? I haven't found a way to hide the **back-button** yet)

## ACTIVITY

```
    class PinCodeActivity, HasTitleBar {
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_pin_code)
            initTitleBarWith(this)
            hideNavigation()
        }

        override fun onResume() {
            super.onResume()
            hideNavigation()
        }

        fun hideNavigation() {
            window.decorView.apply {
                systemUiVisibility = FLAGS
            }
        }

        override fun onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean) {
            super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus)
            hideNavigation()
        }
    }

const val FLAGS = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY)
```

## TITLE-BAR

```
    fun HasTitleBar.initTitleBarWith(activity: Activity, resId: Int = R.id.titleBar) {
        val langButton = activity.findViewById<View>(resId).findViewById<Button>(R.id.tbLanguageChoiceBtn)
        val wrapper = ContextThemeWrapper(activity, R.style.MyPopupMenu)
        val popupMenu = PopUpLanguageMenu(wrapper, langButton)
        langButton.setOnClickListener {
            activity.hideNavigation()
            popupMenu.showMenu()
            activity.hideNavigation()
        }
    }
```

## POP-UP MENU

```
    class PopUpLanguageMenu constructor(context: Context, view: View) : PopupMenu(context, view) {

        private var popupHelper: MenuPopupHelper

        init {
            val popUpMenu = PopupMenu(context, view).apply {
                inflate(R.menu.menu_language_dropdown)
            }

            popupHelper = MenuPopupHelper(context, popUpMenu.menu as MenuBuilder, view)
            popupHelper.run {
                gravity = Gravity.END
                setForceShowIcon(true)
            }
        }

        fun showMenu() {
            popupHelper.show()
        }
    }
```

**EXPECTED RESULT**: Navigation-bar & it's icons are hidden, after the pop-up menu is shown, the icons are still *HIDDEN*

**ACTUAL RESULT**: Navigation-bar & it's icons are hidden, after the pop-up menu is shown, the icons are *SHOWN*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nav bar re-appears because there is a new DecorView (PopupDecorView) is newly drawn on the top of the Views stack, which isn't affected by your FLAGs set before.

There is no silver bullet here, my approach is to dig into the WindowManagerGlobal by reflection and catch out the peek View, apply the system FLAGs on it again, so after the PopupMenu shows up, it manages to hide the Navigation bar right after that (there is still, a show up from the Navigation Bar once).

Here is the code:

```
override fun onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus)
    if (hasFocus) {
        hideNavigation()
    } else {
        // When PopupMenu appears, the current Activity looses the focus
        setFlagsOnThePeekView() // Hijack to the current peek view, apply the Flags on it
    }
}

@SuppressLint("PrivateApi")
fun setFlagsOnThePeekView() {
    try {
        val wmgClass = Class.forName("android.view.WindowManagerGlobal")
        val wmgInstance = wmgClass.getMethod("getInstance").invoke(null)
        val viewsField = wmgClass.getDeclaredField("mViews")
        viewsField.isAccessible = true

        val views = viewsField.get(wmgInstance) as ArrayList<View>
        // When the popup appears, its decorView is the peek of the stack aka last item
        views.last().apply { 
            systemUiVisibility = FLAGS
            setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener {
                systemUiVisibility = FLAGS
            }
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

Comment: Works wonderfully! It's the only solution that works without fault.

Comment: Using protected classes should definitely be avoided since it might not work on some devices in production.

Comment: @SarthakMishra as I mentioned, there is no silver bullet solution here yet, if you do know one we're all ears. Your concern is right, but need to be put in the right context as well. Do you launch a KIOS app publicly without knowing the destination installing device/OS? :D

Comment: I understand man that it's a hack. It would be better if you could mention the ramifications of using the solution in a production app. That would help someone who isn't that advanced in android development to understand what they are signing up for :)

Answer (score 1):

Because PopupMenu use new DecorView (PopupDecorView), try:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if(hasFocus)
    {
        fullSceen(getWindow().getDecorView());
    }
    else {
        try {
            Object wmgInstance = Class.forName("android.view.WindowManagerGlobal").getMethod("getInstance").invoke(null);
            Field viewsField = Class.forName("android.view.WindowManagerGlobal").getDeclaredField("mViews");

            viewsField.setAccessible(true);
            ArrayList<View> views = (ArrayList<View>) viewsField.get(wmgInstance);
            for (View view: views) {
                fullSceen(view);

                view.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
                        fullSceen(view);
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        AppUtils.console(this,TAG, "hasFocus == false");
    }
}
private void fullSceen(View view){
    view.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
}
```